# Convert List of Tree View nodes to combined record

Tags: c#, linq, treeview, ilist, radtreeview

I have no sample code in this instance because i havent a clue where to start and its killing me!

Basically i have a RadTreeView collection of nodes that are checked and these are returned as

```
IList<RadTreeNode> nodeCollection = RadTreeView1.CheckedNodes;
```

The format of these values is as follows,

> 001001009001, 001001009002, 001001009003, 001001009004, 001001009005,
>   001001010002, 001001010003

This may seem complicated but each set of 3 numbers refers to an element eg 001 001 009 001

I have 5 privileges in total which are reflected by the final three characters, these may be checked or unchecked if they are not in the list i'd like a zero in the output otherwise a one. The other groups refer to locations

> Sample output:  001,001,009,1,1,1,1,1  (because in this instance all
>   five privs have been checked) 001,001,010,0,1,1,0,0 (because only 2 &
>   3 have been checked)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Show()
{
    IEnumerable<string> lst = new string[]{"001001009001", "001001009002", 
       "001001009003", "001001009004", "001001009005", "001001010002", 
       "001001010003" };
    var res = Process(lst);
    forech(string str in res)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
static List<string> Process(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    Dictionary<string, int[]> elements = new Dictionary<string,int[]>();

    foreach (var str in input)
    {
        string element = str.Substring(0, 9);
        int privelegeNumber = int.Parse(str.Substring(9, 3));
        if (!elements.ContainsKey(element))
        {
            elements.Add(element, Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5).ToArray());
        }
        elements[element][privelegeNumber - 1] = 1;
    }
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(21);
        sb.Append(element.Key.Substring(0, 3));
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(element.Key.Substring(3, 3));
        sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append(element.Key.Substring(6, 3));
        foreach (int privelege in element.Value)
        {
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(privelege);
        }
        result.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(0,5).ToArray()` can be changed to `new int[5]` since all the values will default to 0 anyway.  But otherwise this is more or less how I would do it.  +1.

Comment: Thanks, but since c# gives an error on non initialized values, i don't rely on default values and always initialize variables explisitly

Comment: Thanks Dmitry this is perfect!! +1 for introduing me to Dictionary as well :)